# Несовпадение подписи сообщения приватным ключом в Android Java и PHP

Tags: php, java, android, rsa, sha256

День добрый, господа разработчики! Прошу помощи и совета. Преамбулу, что я новенький в программировании под Android и тд и тп опустим.
Итак. Разрабатываю приложение которому по протоколу обмена с API необходимо каждый свой запрос подписывать электронным приватным ключом (самоподписанным).
Эта подпись на сервере проверяется с помощью PHP и публичного ключа. Приватный ключ, необходимый для подписания запроса лежит в raw в виде .pfx
Вот так я его читаю:

> ```
> public static PrivateKey getCompanyPrivateKey(Context myContext) {
> String keyAlias = null;
> KeyStore keystore = null;
> PrivateKey key = null;
> Enumeration aliases = null;
>
> InputStream is;
> try {
> is = myContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.company);
> keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
> } catch ( KeyStoreException e) {
> return null;
> }
> try {
> assert keystore != null;
> keystore.load(is, PKCS_PASSWD.toCharArray());
> } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException e) {
> return null;
> }
> try {
> aliases = keystore.aliases();
> } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
> //e.printStackTrace();
> return null;
> }
> assert aliases != null;
> while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
> keyAlias = (String) aliases.nextElement();
> }
> try {
> key = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(keyAlias, PKCS_PASSWD.toCharArray());
> } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableKeyException e ) {
> return null;
> }
> return key;
> }
> ```

Вот так подписываю:

> ```
> public static String openssl_sign(PrivateKey privateKey, String plainText) {
> byte[] signature = null;
> try {
> Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
> sig.initSign(privateKey);
> sig.update(plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
> signature = sig.sign();
> } catch(Exception ex) {
> ex.printStackTrace();
> }
> return Base64.encodeToString(signature, Base64.DEFAULT);
> }
> ```

Все это работает без ошибок. Я получаю приватный ключи из .pfx и подпись строки в виде base64.

> n4TLl9Lz86ufMdp4M2an/8Dwg+NuZ//+QvxSgbPZglr9af62jGKuh0omp2DWSK6BCapuSaC+c99w
> w5bbgnzbbajNUakLUDC2A+hgd0yn4XKOducp0TpSbadw6zprvA1UoXzUUfot/R5g8Fpmg1slrGY5
> 0ohB6u5EJ1wEI60yT3e1uz5KKSdJKh3pYr/WVHyfBGOvuyqRAFVkSElHh7QCuFCxxYrMQTXeOxzP
> YuO6u7KF69EYsKe6tlgf+cKntwtBoiQJa1nCMAYslB0DZxVDruxcKCX12yvwGoTlNgtbdADuh+WZ
> +SDBqdkUFoMxx6zkFJ64E4tI/UbPW+YWfOojZA==

Проблема заключается в том, что тот же самый алгоритм реализованный на PHP

> ```
> $data = file_get_contents('./company.p12');
> $certPassword = 'UiO389jh';
> openssl_pkcs12_read($data, $certs, $certPassword);
> $pkey = openssl_pkey_get_private( $certs['pkey'] );
>
> function signJsonString( $private_key = '', $jsonString = '' ) {
> $result = '';
> if ( is_string( $jsonString ) && trim( strval( $jsonString ) ) != '' ) {
> $binarySignature = '';
> if ( openssl_sign( $jsonString, $binarySignature, $private_key, 'sha256WithRSAEncryption' ) ) {
> $result = base64_encode( $binarySignature );
> }
> }
> return $result;
> }
> $jsonString = '{"signupid":"2150bf6609de47a9b0233a3a458cbfbc"}';
> $signature = signJsonString($pkey, $jsonString);
> echo $signature;
> ```

дает совершенно другую подпись в формате base64.

> wnq0zhTm3cu2zwUQR9fbyxXP8Bj07W5rHbQ22iWhcyGNWURoz1tPosw5Rdg6i/1zGI9G++8F3Lt+
> XlkXtsjzNoIRyaReZ8FUhQO4CPu1eT5B4z5sEYlGbdqr81+RX2tny9K1PcS3OpMXdg80GDvBZzY9
> ktldh4a66tEqoAa5sMWc91fDdmm3MTSVm0L8l5WD2mXCsBLKVLkA/ejt+HD0f5v6t1W9rbmOJBD8
> hAs5pTrpRNte1fuOhgpwLUgFXzvyoPKVBdB6GQs5v1eRfkEj/hWk3/CdifPZvr1VMAOS+M4XaXGm
> b4n6RtknHprSpU78gF/ZAkOSvtF7j8LUIE5M6A==

Естественно алгоритмы подписи одни и теже и в Java и в PHP, .pfx-файл тоже один и тот же, сама подписываемая строка тоже абсолютно идентична в обоих случаях.

Бьюсь уже несколько месяцев. Перечитал тонны советов и подсказок. Затер stackoverflow уже до дыр, но так и не нашел конца ниточки за которую бы стоило потянуть.
Во всех похожих случаях пишут уверенно только одно - подпись на PHP верна. Искать нужно в Java. Чувствую, что ларчик открывается просто, но собственных познаний в Java пока не хватает. Буду рад любой помощи и подсказке. Готов предоставить желающим помочь все необходимые файлы.

P.S Знакомый Java-программист написал на "чистой" Java пример (https://bitbucket.org/andryha/signtext/src/master/) и у него там подпись сошлась c PHP. Но на Android этого не происходит.

Comment: Вот этот ответ смотрели? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56301628/java-mac-sha256-hashing-does-not-match-with-php-hmac-sha256-using-pack ? Очень похоже на правду. Надо заменить plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) на код из ответа

Comment: Боюсь, что это не то что мне нужно. В Вашем примере есть две функции, одна преобразует строку в 16-ричном формате в массив байт (hexToString), а вторая преобразует строку в массив байт (StringToBytes).  В моем случае на вход в
`sig.update(plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

нужно подавать именно массив байт. Стандартная функция `string.getBytes` ничем не отличается от `stringToBytes`. Так что, предложенное Вами решение - решением моей проблемы не является :(

Comment: hexToString и StringToBytes преобразовывает все в массив байт, так как и нужно. В чем проблема? И метод string.getBytes отличается от stringToBytes. В андроид sdk он другой

Comment: `hexToString` - на вход подается строка в hex-формате так как в вышеуказанном вопросе у автора переменная `secretKey` является hex-строкой, не вижу смысла перевода моего `plainText` в формат `hex` чтобы получить на выходе тоже самое. `stringToBytes` и `string.getBytes` различаются по реализации, но по логике это одно и тоже. За помощь спасибо. Я их на всякий случай конечно попробовал - но все равно получил ту же самую подпись, что и при стандартном `string.getBytes`

Comment: Эхх... Похоже не там я ищу `Android`-разработчиков знающих ответ на мой вопрос...

Comment: Эхх. А я вот решил твой вопрос и уже понёсся сюда писать ответ. Но после твоего комментария решил, что раз тут такие плохие разработчики сидят, решай-ка ты его сам, раз такой умный. Но за вопрос спасибо, некоторые нюансы для себя прояснил. Удачи

Comment: Ну во-первых я никого не оскорблял. И не писал что тут плохие разработчики. Я написал, что похоже, что тут нет тех кто может решить мой вопрос. И не совсем понимаю чем это Вас так разобидел. А за совет искать самому - спасибо :). Я так и делаю в тех случаях когда помощи ждать неоткуда/ Думаю рано или поздно - найду :) Еще раз спасибо за пожелание удачи. :)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/W8cZ7vbx пример кода. тоже самоподписный сертификат. только не в pfx, а в андроид кейсторе, генерируется на лету при первом запуске приложения. потом при получении подписи проверка подписи в 1с через .net-рефлекшены в ком по открытому ключу, который приложение передает при регистрации. вроде все совпадало существенной разницы с вашим кодом нет. ну кроме источника закрытого ключа.